# Python to SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am making a project where I connect to a database with Python then update and change things. I have run into problems when trying to retrieve information.

I am using this code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Project.db')

print ("Opened database sucessfully")

cursor = conn.execute("SELECT ID,ResidentTitle,ResidentForname FROM Residents")
for row in cursor:
    print ("ID = "), row[0]
    print ("ResidentTitle ="), row[1]
    print ("Name ="), row[2]

print ("done");
conn.close()
```

from this I am getting back the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/sqlite/Sqlplz.py", line 7, in <module>
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT ID,ResidentTitle,ResidentForname FROM Residents")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Residents
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You are missing space. `FROMResidents` must be `FROM Residents`

Comment: @Alexander: the SQL in your code doesn't match the SQL in the error message; double-check that they're both up-to-date?

Comment: @nickgrim updated thank you.

Comment: Wait, where is the confusion? Error message says everything. There is no table `Residents` in the database.

Comment: Is the file *Project.db* in the current directory? If not, then the connect statement creates a new empty database.

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT ID,ResidentTitle,ResidentForname FROMResidents")
-------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You are missing space, you should update like that

```
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT ID,ResidentTitle,ResidentForname FROM Residents")
```

Comment: i uploaded the wrong code, i updated the problem, sorry.

Comment: @Alexander,  did you create Residents table?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed, issue with a broken save file.